# NID cookie for youtube-nocookie.com

Tags: youtube, data-protection

My ultimate goal is to make the web site GRPR compliant that contains Youtube embed videos. Originally I used youtube.com, but then found youtube-nocookie.com, but it creates the NID cookie. Does it violate the GDPR principle? Ghostery tracker doesn't detect trackers in this case, but requests come in Chrome Network.

[image: Chrome Newtwork]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any first or third-party cookies require consent except for those "strictly necessary" to provide the service, so for example first-party session cookies to store login status do not need permission, load balancer ones probably don't either, especially if they are short-lived.

Ghostery isn't a great authority because they accept payment from ad companies to ignore certain cookies. Try Ublock Origin and Better tracker blockers for a more ethical take.

youtube-nocookie.com is probably just a proxy that strips cookies - but there's nothing preventing you from building that functionality yourself - nginx is easy to configure as a proxy and can strip cookies.

This is all somewhat vague because you don't show details of the cookies you mention, what domains they are coming from, what kind of cookies they are, what's in them, how long they live etc, and all of those things have some bearing. Fundamentally, cookies don't themselves violate GDPR, but tracking cookies without consent certainly do.

Comment: thanks. But do you kow if http://youtube-nocookie.com is already GDPR compliant out of the box? Unblock Origin shows that requests come, but maybe this proxy doesn't send any private information, so we can be sure that personal data is not shared.

Comment: From what I've found, it seems that youtube-nocookie.com was created in 2009, but that it has to a large extent fallen out of use because of changes in youtube itself. The main difference seems to be that it delays setting any cookies until a "play" button is clicked, rather than on page load, so you might want to check that, and even then it needs to ask for consent.

Comment: Can you provide an example link? It's hard to say anything definitive without something to inspect.

Comment: http://sharktoy.dev.cooa.la/search/fr?filter=gdpr shows a Youtube embed video (http://youtube-nocookie.com/)

Comment: Well on that page, youtube-nocookie.com does indeed not set any cookies, but twitter sets 13 and facebook sets 8, so you're not in the clear yet!

Comment: On the one hand _it delays setting any cookies until a "play" button is clicked_, But on the other hand it _does indeed not set any cookies_. So, how does it really work? Is it a GDPR solution, can we be confident? Is any official documentation with such info? (google developed it). So, now it sounds like my original question.

Comment: From my point of view we can not be sure that cookies will not be tracked, because in Youtube it said _until a "play"_. so, I think before playing the video I should show a cookie consent question.

Answer (score 0):

https://policies.google.com/technologies/types?hl=en-US

That cookie is used to store user preferences, not for usage or advertising tracking.